# mongodb - how to get limited number of items from array

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

---

is it possible somehow to get limited number of items from array?
For now I just can get whoole users data, but I want to have a pagination, where I can load limited number of tasks from users data

---

```
async getUserTasks( _id, _limit ) {
    try {
        await UserModel.find( {
            _id: _id,
            "tasks": { $size: _limit }
        } );
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log( e );
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyLa2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Use `limit` to cap the number of documents that can be returned from a read operation. `limit` functions as a cap on the maximum number of documents that the operation can return, but the operation can return a smaller number of documents if there are not enough documents present to reach the limit. If `limit` is used with the `skip` method, the `skip` applies first and the limit only applies to the documents left over after the `skip`.

Follow the instructions in the examples below to insert data into a collection and return only certain results from a query using a sort, a skip, and a limit. Consider the following collection of documents that describe books:

```
[
  { "_id": 1, "name": "The Brothers Karamazov", "author": "Dostoyevsky", "length": 824 },
  { "_id": 2, "name": "Les Misérables", "author": "Hugo", "length": 1462 },
  { "_id": 3, "name": "Atlas Shrugged", "author": "Rand", "length": 1088 },
  { "_id": 4, "name": "Infinite Jest", "author": "Wallace", "length": 1104 },
  { "_id": 5, "name": "Cryptonomicon", "author": "Stephenson", "length": 918 },
  { "_id": 6, "name": "A Dance With Dragons", "author": "Tolkein", "length": 1104 },
]
```

Limit

The following example queries the collection to return the top three longest books. It matches all the documents with the query, applies a sort on the length field to return books with longer lengths before books, and applies a limit to return only 3 results:

```
// define an empty query document
const query = {};
// sort in descending (-1) order by length
const cursor = collection.find(query).sort({ length: -1 }).limit(3);
await cursor.forEach(console.dir);
```

The code example above outputs the following three documents, sorted by length:

```
{ "_id": 2, "title": "Les Misérables", "author": "Hugo", "length": 1462 }
{ "_id": 6, "title": "A Dance With Dragons", "author": "Martin", "length": 1104 }
{ "_id": 4, "title": "Infinite Jest", "author": "Wallace", "length": 1104 }
```

Comment: Hello, I found the solution

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice

in my case it will be:

return await UserModel.find({ "_id": _id }, { "tasks": { $slice: +_limit } } )

Anyway, thank you for help